# RKhunter Does Not Perform All Checks

Tags: rkhunter

Can someone tell me how to config / force rkhunter to check everything on my system?   The checks are skipped, even if I run `rkhunter --checkall`

```
Performing malware checks
    Checking running processes for suspicious files          [ None found ]
    Checking for hidden processes                            [ Skipped ]

Applications checks...
    All checks skipped
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I do not see a "checkall" in the man page https://linux.die.net/man/8/rkhunter

Comment: Curiously, "checkall" is mention on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter).

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason my application scans were being ignored when I used the --checkall modifier because in my /etc/rkhunter.conf file the "apps" option was by default included the `DISABLE_TESTS` options.  Removing it enabled my applications to scanned.

```
#
# These two options determine which tests are to be performed. The ENABLE_TESTS
# option can use the word 'ALL' to refer to all of the available tests. The
# DISABLE_TESTS option can use the word 'NONE' to mean that no tests are
# disabled. The list of disabled tests is applied to the list of enabled tests.
#
# Both options are space-separated lists of test names, and both options may
# be specified more than once. The currently available test names can be seen
# by using the command 'rkhunter --list tests'.
#
# The supplied configuration file has some tests already disabled, and these
# are tests that will be used only occasionally, can be considered 'advanced'
# or that are prone to produce more than the average number of false-positives.
#
# Please read the README file for more details about enabling and disabling
# tests, the test names, and how rkhunter behaves when these options are used.
#
# The default values are to enable all tests and to disable none. However, if
# either of the options below are specified, then they will override the
# program defaults.
#
ENABLE_TESTS=ALL
#DISABLE_TESTS=suspscan hidden_ports hidden_procs deleted_files packet_cap_apps apps
DISABLE_TESTS=suspscan hidden_ports deleted_files packet_cap_apps ipc_shared_mem
```

For any fellow rkhunter "noobies"

https://sourceforge.net/    <-- has the primary support / info for rkhunter

I also recommend that you:
1.) (#) comment out DISABLE_TESTS in /etc/rkhunter.conf
2.) use virtualbox to set up a test server (duplicate equivalent environment) and run checksums to verify false positives
3.) Use various forms of "whitelist" in /etc/rkhunter.conf to clear all warnings
4.) install a linux app called "unhide" so that you can scan hidden ports and hidden directories